# What does "Espada" mean in connection with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-3

I am considering buying a Raspberry Pi 3 in Kazakhstan where I live. For some reason the seller here lists their Raspberry Pi as "Espada Raspberry Pi". If you look at the non-Cyrillic characters on [the seller's website](http://unit.kz/?q=132434), you can see what I mean. I could not find out what connection any company or OS called Espada has to do with Raspberry Pi. As the price has the usual Kazakhstan markup on foreign imported goods I would be surprised if these were fakes, but the concern is there.

So my question is: What does "Espada" mean in connection with Raspberry Pi? Is it an authorised distributor, a bootlegging company, an OS or something else?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't offer much help. A google search of "espada" shows lots of hits for websites on the .ru TLD. It translates as "blade" or "sword" into English and is supposed to be a Spanish word. Could it be a translation error and refer to the Pi's form factor. There is a "contact us" link at the top of the website you link to. Perhaps they could tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espada (espada-tech.ru; [translated](https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?u=http://www.espada-tech.ru/)) appear to be a Russian computer company. They sell Pis from raspberry.su ([translated](https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fraspberry.su)).

**It's unclear how they're related to the official Pi distributors**; my guess would be that they're not official as I couldn't find any mention of them on an official reseller list, such as [Farnell's list](http://farnell.com/raspberrypi-consumer/approved-retailers.php). It was pretty challenging to even find any mention of them on the English language internet, which would be odd if they were official. For comparison, [the official reseller's company name](https://www.google.com/search?q=baltelectron%20raspberry%20pi) does come up in a search result for approved resellers.

I'd honestly be surprised if a convincing fake of a Pi could be made; the costs involved in finding a SoC that could be passed off as the Pi's for less money than the Pi Foundation make it for would be great. They're probably just unofficially reselling Pis that they buy elsewhere and ship in, but it's impossible to know without seeing one of the devices they sell.